# Loadbalancer targetPort not forwarding to daemonset hostPort if port not same as hostPort

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have the following setup:

A loadbalancer points to an ingress controller as daemonset, running in a gcp-kubernetes-cluster, as seen in the example below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: lb
  namespace: ns
  labels:
    app: lb
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: x.x.x.x
  ports:
      - name: test1
        port: 445
        targetPort: test

      - name: test2
        port: 444
        targetPort: test
  selector:
    k8s-app: ingress-controller
```

Here is the daemonset for the ingress-controller

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: ingress-controller
  namespace: ns
  labels:
    k8s-app: ingress-controller
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ingress-controller
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ingress-controller
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      containers:
        - name: ingress-controller
          image: gcr.io/google_containers/nginx-ingress-controller:0.9.0-beta.15
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "0.3Gi"
              cpu: "0.3"
            limits:
              memory: "0.5Gi"
              cpu: "0.5"
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          ports:
            - name: test
              hostPort: 444
              containerPort: 443
          env:
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - --ingress-class=public
            - --default-backend-service=ns/default-http-backend
            - --v=2
```

The ingress then points to a plain nginx, for test purposes.

Now I encounter the following problem:

When I call the domain for the loadbalancer with the port 444 (test.mydomain.com:444), I successfully receive the nginx-default index page.

However, when I call the domain with the port 445 (test.mydomain.com:445), I would expect to get the same result, since the target port of the load-balancer block is the same, but it doesn't work.

So it seems, that the `port` and `hostPort` have to match.

It seems, that targetPort in the loadbalancer doesn't work as expected, it somehow only forwards `port`of lb to `hostPort` of ingress controller.

I already tried several things, for example configuring the ingress-controller without a `hostPort`, use a completely different port for `hostPort` etc., but I never got the expected result. I've seen working examples in the internet without using `hostPort`, however, they never used daemonsets, but only deployments.

How do I have to configure a loadbalancer and a ingress-controller-daemonset to get different ports route to the same result?

If more information is required, please let me know!

Comment: I would suggest that you try the workaround which is to use the numeric port instead of the name. As a next step, I would recommend that you report this bug to the k8s devs on GitHub to get more assistance

Comment: what error do you get when you call port 445?